# Send as a parameter of a function an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ant design, table component. 
Also i use search feature for each column of data.

```js
 const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
          ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
   
          ..
          ..
```

`getColumnSearchProps` is the function that sends asa a parameter the value that should be searched. It accept as an argument, a string.

I want to send as argument 2 strings. For this i used this:

```js
 const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
          ...this.getColumnSearchProps(['name', 'age'].forEach(i => i)),
        ...
         ..
```

I want to loop and to send `getColumnSearchProps` 2 strings, this is why i used forEach, but it doesn't work, because i should pass in another way these 2 values. How to add these 2 values from array as parameters in `getColumnSearchProps` ?

Comment: How does `getColumnSearchProps` look like? can't you tweak the function to accept an array as a parameter and then loop it inside the function and get the props?

Comment: Instead of for each you could use the spread operator `getColumnSearchProps(...["name", "age"])`

Answer (score 0):

if it only accepts string as paramater, then there's no way to pass anything else but string. however you can try to change the function behavior